# How can I create multiple iam users with console logins enabled with terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, multiple-users

I need to be able to create multiple iam accounts for my developer group with console login enabled using terraform

It's a bit tricky since we have to use keybase when enabling login profiles in terraform. Is there a way to achieve this

```
variable "iam_users" {
  description = "List of iam users that that needs to be created"
  type = "list"
}

# values assigned in .tfvars file
iam_users = ["mahela","bhanuka","duminda"]

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "login_profile" {
  count = "${length(var.iam_users)}"
  user = "${element(var.iam_users,count.index)}"
  password_reset_required = true
  pgp_key = "keybase:mahela"
}
```

I cannot get the output for this list of users from below code since count is define in the resource

```
output "password" {
  value = "${aws_iam_user_login_profile.login_profile.encrypted_password}"
}
```

Do I have to use modules when creating users? with that help to get the output of encrypted password for each user?
Also do I have to use different keybase usernames for each user? this is going to be tricky again :(

Answer (score 3):

When `count` is set in a `resource` block, references to that resource in other expressions produce a list of instance objects rather than a single instance object, and so you can't access the instance attributes directly.

If you wish to return a map from user to password then you can write an `output` expression like the following, assuming you're using Terraform 0.12 or later:

```
output "passwords" {
  value = { for p in aws_iam_user_login_profile.login_profile : p.user => p.encrypted_password }
}
```

A Terraform 0.11-compatible variant of that would be something like the following:

```
output "passwords" {
  value = "${zipmap(aws_iam_user_login_profile.login_profile.*.user, aws_iam_user_login_profile.login_profile.*.encrypted_password)}"
}
```

Comment: I found an error `A managed resource "aws_iam_user" "iam_users" has not been declared in the root module.` can you tell me how to define **resource "aws_iam_user"** for this example